# When I try to click on anything in offcanvas bootstrap5 it closes, just like when I click outside the offcanvas

Tags: bootstrap-5, off-canvas-menu

When I click the button the off-canvas popup but when I click on it, it closes just like when I click outside of it
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
   
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasExample"
        aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
        Button with data-bs-target
    </button>

    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasExample" aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasExampleLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
            <div>
                Some text as placeholder. In real life you can have the elements you have chosen. Like, text, images,
                lists, etc.
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown mt-3">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                    Dropdown button
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

I even copy the exact code from the official site bootstrap5

Those are the images of result the first image is the button and the second is offcanvas popup but the moment I click on it closes

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

hi there I had the same problem, I solve this problem by changing place offcanvas content (modal). it  wors perfectly

Comment: Show your code.